# Can I display query results without naming columns?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Is there a php or html code to dynamically generate a table.

**query :**

`"SELECT * FROM table1;`

Can I display this grid of info without any specifics.
IF there are `4 rows` and `4 columns` I want the table to be that size; if `5x5` than that.

It seems like this should be possible, but all code I can find wants me to specify names or columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are a couple different ways to do this, but for illustration I will assume that the result of your query is stored in a variable called `$results`, which is simply a multidimensional array that you can loop through using a double foreach to dynamically produce your table.

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        echo '<td>' . $col . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

OR if you don't have a `$results` array and are instead getting query results *and* building the table at the same time, something like this might be more appropriate for your needs:

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        echo '<td>' . $col . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I get PHP "Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" Do i need to define $row or $col in anyway?

Comment: @wlraider70 No need to define `$row` and `$col` - they are defined within the loop. You just need to have a valid `$result` array. See my recent update, maybe that will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo'<table>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row[colname].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Instead of just pasting code as an answer, please explain why your answer works so the question author understands why it fixes their problem. It will also help people in the future find similar solutions.